# Why I can't show score of loaded pickled deep learning model?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pickle

I am trying to compare different algorithms for my sentiment analysis project. When I try to load my pickled pre-trained model I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'score3_9' error

Here is my code for loading model:

```
import pickle
import joblib

load_pickle_file = open('LSTM_MODEL3_9.pkl', 'rb')
loaded_model = pickle.load(load_pickle_file)

result = loaded_model.score3_9()

print(result)
```

and here is code of my model:

```
classifier= Sequential()
classifier.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix] ,mask_zero=True))
classifier.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.4,recurrent_dropout=0.5,return_sequences=True))
classifier.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.5,recurrent_dropout=0.4,return_sequences=True))
classifier.add(LSTM(64,dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.summary()

LSTM_FIT = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=6, verbose=1)

score3_9 = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print("Test Accuracy:", score3_9[1])
print("Test Score:", score3_9[0])


joblib.dump(classifier, 'LSTM_MODEL3_9.pkl')


with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory, the model does not contain random variables that you defined in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The classifier you're saving doesn't actually have the results inside it. They appear to be stored in the variable `score3_9`. To fix this, or save the results with the model, the following code would work:

```python
# model definition here...

LSTM_FIT = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=6, verbose=1)

score3_9 = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print("Test Accuracy:", score3_9[1])
print("Test Score:", score3_9[0])

save_data = {'classifier':classifier, 'score':score3_9}


joblib.dump(save_data, 'LSTM_MODEL3_9.pkl')


with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Which you could then access like so:

```python
import pickle
import joblib

load_pickle_file = open('LSTM_MODEL3_9.pkl', 'rb')
loaded_model = pickle.load(load_pickle_file)

result = loaded_model['score']

print(result)
```